# Iterating a NSArray populated from JSON

Tags: ios, nsjsonserialization

I am initialising the following NSArray using JSON;

```
categorias = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:nil error:nil];
```

I can retrieve the number of objects in the array logging it:

```
NSLog(@"NUMERO DE EMPRESAS = %lu", (unsigned long)[categorias count]);
```

The expected number of objects is 24, the log is correct.

```
NUMERO DE EMPRESAS = 24
```

Now, what I need is to iterate the 24 objects and show the value for the key 'latitud'

```
for (int i=0; i<[categorias count]; i++) {
    NSString *lalitudText = x; 
    NSLog (@"EL VALOR ES %@", latitudText);  
}
```

What should I put instead of x, to obtain the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the old syntax you can put this:

```
NSString *lalitudText = [[categorias objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"latitude"];
```

The new syntax lets you do this:

```
NSString *lalitudText = categorias[i][@"latitude"];
```

Comment: categorias[i]; causes some problems with old version of SDK-compiler, but from 6.x works fine :). objectAtIndex is Obj-C style :P

Comment: Thank you, but this shows the whole content from the object at index i, I need the content of only one key, latitude.

Comment: @mvasco reply only one time ... see above solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [fast enumeration](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Collections/Articles/Enumerators.html):

```
for (NSDictionary *element in categorias) {
    NSLog (@"EL VALOR ES %@", element[@"lalitud"]);
}
```

Of course you have to adjust the key of the "lalitud" thingy.

Comment: Thank you, but this shows the whole content from the object at index i, I need the content of only one key, latitude. –

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
NSString *lalitudText = [categorias objectAtIndex:i];
```

Comment: Thank you, but this shows the whole content from the object at index i, I need the content of only one key, latitude. –

Comment: [categorias objectAtIndex:i]; returns Object at index. You can find in this object another objects and more.